# Оформление и ограничение связей в django

Tags: python, база-данных, django

В проекте есть 4 модели.
Первая содержит все объекты, их категорию и какие-то характеристики.
Вторая - все возможные связи объект - дочерний объект.
Третья - связи объект - категория дочернего объекта.
Четвёртая - конфликты объектов.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class Connection(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ChildCategory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_category = models.ForeignKey(????????, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    required = models.IntegerField(blank=True)


class Conflict(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conflict_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Представляется, всё должно работать таким образом, что:

1. У выбранного пользователем объекта программа определяет категории дочерних объектов. Количество  категорий дочерних объектов у объекта = количество возможных связей от объекта.
2. Выбирает все возможные дочерние объекты, группируя по категориям.
3. Для дочерних объектов делает то же самое, что в пункте 1.
4. Доходит до объектов, у которых нет вариантов дочерних, и получает древо возможных вариантов.
5. Граф(ограниченный условиями пользователя, единственностью каждого объекта в структуре и конфликтами в 4й таблице - когда один объект есть, второго нет) проходит по древу, определяя наилучший вариант структуры.

Во всех таблицах, кроме 3й, просто связи один к одному, как мне кажется (хотя, могу ошибаться).
А в третьей совсем не уверен. Должно ли вместо вопросов стоять просто **Item.category**, или  это связь один ко многим? Где и как тогда указывать программе, что выбирать надо дочерний объект из группы с такой-то категорией?

Answer (score 0):

В первой модели ты хранишь объекты и их категории.
Так как дочерние объекты это по сути те же сами объекты, то получается, что ты в ней же хранишь и категории дочернего объекта. Во второй модели ты хранишь связи между объектами.
По сути во второй таблице у тебя уже хранятся связи между объектом и категориями дочерних объектов(так как сами категории хранятся там же где и сам объект). поэтому, вообще не понятна необходимость в третьей модели.

Я бы вынес категории в отдельную модель, что бы избежать разночтения, когда у тебя ссылка на объект Item является в одном случае ссылкой на объект, в другом случае на категорию.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


class Connection(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

по сути модель Connection можно упразднить, добавив в модель Item
children = models.ManyToMany('Item', related_name='parents')
или, если хочется оставить модель, на случай, если планируются какие-либо дополнительный характеристики для этой связи в дальнейшем указывать, то можно добавить в `Item`
`connections = models.ManyToMany('Item', related_name='connections', through='Connection',)`

`class Conflict(models.Model)`

аналогично с предыдущей моделью, либо упраздняем, либо просто добавляем в `Item`
`conflicts = models.ManyToMany('Item', related_name='conflicts', through='Conflict')`

теперь, если нужно отдельно сохранять список дочерних категорий, для каждого объекта, тогда получается

```
class ChildCategory(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    required = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

опять таки, в модель `Item` добавляем строку
`children_categories = models.ManyToMany(Category, related_names='children_categories', through='ChildCategory')`

Comment: Да, это или сложно на первый взгляд, или я не очень понятно описал.
Предположим: в первой таблице(=модели) все объекты 1, 2(категория a), 3(категория б), 4(категория б), ..., N. Во второй связи 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, ... . А в третьей 1 - категория а, 1 - категория б, 2 - категория в, ... .
Изначально я предполагал, что программа будет брать исходный объект(1), смотреть возможные категории дочерних объектов для него(категория а и б) в таблице 3, и брать для категории дочерние объекты в таблице 2(объекты 3/4 для категории б и 2 для категории а).

Comment: Чисто визуально это представлялось логично - сразу видно в таблице бд, сколько и каких дочерних объектов может быть у объекта.
При этом, действительно, кажется, что 3я таблица не нужна, если программа будет получать объект, брать все возможные дочерние объекты во 2й таблице, смотреть категории в 1й таблице, и группировать.
Не знаю пока, как это всё будет выглядеть в виде алгоритма, но что так, что так - разницы особо и нету, а на модель меньше.

Comment: Я внес изменения, как я бы сделал эту структуру